TensorFlow ImportError: undefined symbol: _ZTIN6snappy4SinkE
I'm trying to import TensorFlow in my conda Python environment, but I'm encountering the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
2 device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
4 if device_name != "/device:GPU:0":
File ~/anaconda3/envs/tf-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py:40
37 import typing as _typing
39 # Do not remove this line; See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42596
---> 40 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow # pylint: disable=unused-import
41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
File ~/anaconda3/envs/tf-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py:34
29 from tensorflow.python.platform import self_check
31 # TODO(mdan): Cleanup antipattern: import for side effects.
32
33 # Perform pre-load sanity checks in order to produce a more actionable error.
---> 34 self_check.preload_check()
36 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long
38 try:
39 # This import is expected to fail if there is an explicit shared object
40 # dependency (with_framework_lib=true), since we do not need RTLD_GLOBAL.
File ~/anaconda3/envs/tf-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/self_check.py:63, in preload_check()
50 raise ImportError(
51 "Could not find the DLL(s) %r. TensorFlow requires that these DLLs "
52 "be installed in a directory that is named in your %%PATH%% "
(...)
56 "https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads"
57 % " or ".join(missing))
58 else:
59 # Load a library that performs CPU feature guard checking. Doing this here
60 # as a preload check makes it more likely that we detect any CPU feature
61 # incompatibilities before we trigger them (which would typically result in
62 # SIGILL).
---> 63 from tensorflow.python.platform import _pywrap_cpu_feature_guard
64 _pywrap_cpu_feature_guard.InfoAboutUnusedCPUFeatures()
ImportError: /home/gimhara/anaconda3/envs/tf-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/../../libtensorflow_framework.so.2: undefined symbol: _ZTIN6snappy4SinkE

I'm using Python 3.11 and TensorFlow v2.15.0 installed in an Anaconda environment on Ubuntu 22.04.
From my research, this error seems to be related to a missing or incompatible version of the Snappy compression library used by TensorFlow.
I've tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Reinstalling TensorFlow using pip and conda.

Installing the libsnappy-dev package on Ubuntu.


However, none of these steps have resolved the issue so far.
Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly resolve this ImportError and get TensorFlow running correctly?
Please let me know if you need any additional information or if I should provide more details about my setup or the steps I've taken so far.
Thank you in advance for your help!

The error you’re encountering with TensorFlow is related to an undefined symbol in the Snappy compression library, which TensorFlow relies on for certain operations.TensorFlow 2.15.0 may not be fully compatible with Python 3.11 yet. Ensure you are using a version of Python that is compatible with TensorFlow 2.15.0. For TensorFlow 2.15.0, Python 3.8, 3.9, or 3.10 are generally more stable choices.You can create a new environment with Python 3.10,conda create --name tf-env python=3.10
conda activate tf-env

Reinstall TensorFlow and ensure that all dependencies are properly set up:pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.15.0Since the error involves the Snappy compression library, ensure the necessary libraries are installed on your system
